# Deactivating and uninstalling Zend Opcode caching

Tags: php, linux, caching, virtual-machine, opcode

I have installed the Zend OpCache on my linuxbox. I used the following command to install the extension:

```
sudo pecl install zendopcache-7.0.2
```

Now without modifying my php.ini file, the extension is enabled. This claim is based on the output I am getting for the `php -v` command. Following is the output I am getting for `php -v` command:

> PHP 5.5.14-1+deb.sury.org~precise+1 (cli) (built: Jun 27 2014 
>   14:11:34)  Copyright (c) 1997-2014 The PHP Group   Zend Engine v2.5.0,
>   Copyright (c) 1998-2014 Zend Technologies
>        with Zend OPcache v7.0.4-dev, Copyright (c) 1999-2014, by Zend Technologies

It also seems as Zend Opcode caching is enabled by default. Can someone help me deactivating Zend Opcode caching as I need to evaluate some other Opcode cachings? In my  php.ini file, I dont see any Zend Opcode caching option.
In case if I want to uninstall the Zend Opcode caching completely from my vm, how can I achieve this?

Answer (score 2):

Just disable the opcache module. On a linux system with php 7 run

```
sudo phpdismod opcache
```

on older php 5 systems

```
sudo php5dismod opcache
```

Answer (score 1):

Zend OPcache is integrated since 5.5 if i remember correctly. So no need to install from pecl.
Create a new ini file or use the one available on your system to enable / disable opcache

```
opcache.enable 0
opcache.enable_cli 0
```

Answer (score 1):

Uninstall Opcache by runnning the following command:

```
sudo pecl uninstall zendopcache-7.0.2
```